# Swift Convert curl PUT request to alamofire or URLRequest

Tags: json, swift, curl, alamofire, nsmutableurlrequest

I have an app that controls some IoT devices.   I am trying to make an older iHome outlet work that uses the evrythng API.  It would need to take a command like this:

```
curl -X PUT \
  https://api.evrythng.com/thngs/<DEVICE_ID>/properties/targetpowerstate1 \
  -H 'authorization: MY_API_KEY' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '[{"value":"1"}]'
```

The issue is that the [{"value":"1"}] does not work trying to send as a paramter using alamofire due to the curly braces within the square braces. So I tried using NSMutableURLRequest doing something like:

```
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.evrythng.com/thngs/\(self.id)/properties/targetpowerstate1")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let stringParams = "[{\"value\":\"0\"}]"
        request.httpBody = stringParams.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        request.httpMethod = "PUT"
        request.addValue("no-cache", forHTTPHeaderField: "cache-control")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.addValue(apikey, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            guard error == nil else {
                getvcfunc.statusMsg(error! as! String)
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                getvcfunc.statusMsg("Data is empty")
                return
            }
            let outputStr  = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            getvcfunc.statusMsg(outputStr ?? "no value")
        })
        task.resume()
```

Please help me, I have been trying different things for hours now just to figure out how to send this PUT request with the curly braces.

- Dave

Comment: Your requests seems correct (except your put 0 for the value instead of 1 of your example). Now, `let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)` should be `let request = URLRequest(url: url!)`, avoid using NSStuff in Swift+ when there are Swift version available (and that would avoid you the `as URLRequest` later). But what's the response your are getting?

Comment: You are not setting `Content-Type` header in your Swift code, why?

Comment: OOPer, thank you!  This comment was the solution to the problem.